# I am unable to update the array inside an obj using put request as mention bellow

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Facing issue to update the cart value new entry in obj

I want to push an element inside an array which is inside an obj I am using mockup

### Get request to get cart array

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url : "https://5ef88b09ab.mockapi.io/"+id,
        success:function(responsarr){
            var cart = responsarr.cart
            postaction(cart,id)
        },
        error:function(request){
            console.log(request.status)
        }
        }
    )
```

### Put request function

```
function postaction(cart,id){
cart.push(Number(prductId))
    var settings = {
        "url": "https://5ef88b09ab.mockapi.io/"+id,
        "method": "PUT",
        "data": {"Cart":cart},
      };
      
      $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
}
```

#### accepted output

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "EmailId": "EmailId 1",
    "Cart": [
        2,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "password": "password 1",
    "username": "username 1"
}
```

#### getting output

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "EmailId": "EmailId 1",
    "Cart": [],
    "password": "password 1",
    "username": "username 1",
    "Cart[]": [
        "2",
        "3",
        "4",
        "9"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is responsarr's value?

Comment: The obj which is mentioned in the accepted output tab above

Comment: what's the value of cart after this `var cart = responsarr.cart`

Comment: Cart: [
        2,
        3,
        4]
I am getting the cart array value which is present in the obj

Comment: `function postaction(cart,id){
cart.push(Number(prductId))` In this the prductId value is undefined.

Comment: No Sir, i am declaring the value

Comment: It's unclear, I can suggest put `console.log(cart)`  before `cart.push(Number(prductId))` and after `cart.push(Number(prductId))`. Post the output here. Then I can suggest.

Comment: console.log(cart)  this is the output sir    [2, 3, 4]

Comment: `$.ajax(settings)`  is this one changes the Cart's value?

Comment: Yes this the one call to  change the value of cart

Comment: Then it's specifc to your resquest/API , I cannot change it. It has to be fixed from API side.

Comment: Perhaps the api expects you to send JSON?

Comment: I tried sending it but still facing some issue